# Error in dyn.load(dll_copy_file) --A error when building R package via linux system

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package, fftw

I am currently building a local R package with Rcpp and FFTW3.

When I run **devtools::document()** the error shows up, below is the full error message:

```
Error in dyn.load(dll_copy_file) : 
  unable to load shared object '/tmp/RtmpcsGXOO/pkgload7f8a5462dce4/pmd.so':
  /tmp/RtmpcsGXOO/pkgload7f8a5462dce4/pmd.so: undefined symbol: fftw_execute
```

pmd is my package name. I am wondering it might relate to my Makevar file.

My Makevars.in looks like this:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS=@CPPFLAGS@ @FFTW_CFLAGS@
PKG_LIBS=@LIBS@ @FFTW_LIBS@

all: $(SHLIB)

PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include -I/usr/local/include  
PKG_LIBS= -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3
```

Actually, I have no idea how to write a Makevars file, the way I wrote this Makevars is copying Makevars from other existing packages.

Originally, I used C to perform what I want, and I used dyn.load after typing following codes in terminal so that I could .C() those C functions in R:

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=~/usr/include

export C_INCLUDE_PATH

export LD_RUN_PATH=$HOME/usr/lib

R CMD SHLIB functions.c -I$HOME/usr/include -L$HOME/usr/lib -lfftw3 -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o functions.so
```

.

Comment: Several things could be going wrong. For example, did you declare the function as extern C? Have you tried linking with `-l:libfftw3.so -Wl,-rpath=...`? Does the error occur only with document? Did you add a line with `useDynLib(..., .registration=TRUE)` in the namespace? Without more information it's not possible to tell what exactly is happening.

Comment: The file works fine when I dyn.load its .so file in R. I used the following code in terminal to create the .so file: `C_INCLUDE_PATH=~/usr/include

export C_INCLUDE_PATH

export LD_RUN_PATH=$HOME/usr/lib

R CMD SHLIB functions.c -I$HOME/usr/include -L$HOME/usr/lib -lfftw3 -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o functions.so`  The error happens when documenting and building the package. The useDynLib is added.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. We tend to recommend to break operations down to the actual `R CMD INSTALL ...` and/or `R CMD COMPILE ...` which will likely reveal an issue in your setup.  You could also look at the existing [CRAN package using fftw3](https://cran.r-project.org/package=fftw) and see if you can extend it to / blend it with a package using Rcpp.

Comment: I had "unable to load shared object" thrown during package checking (roxygen2) after upgrading to a machine with an M1 processor. What worked for me: build the package first, and then the error changed into a more informative one that pointed out missing packages.